# C# Unity project, Freezing when ran

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, freeze

I have been working on a Unity2d project for a while now and I recently implemented a method of which my "Enemy" housed in the `GreyGuardController` script would fire a bullet in the direction of which it would be facing, using the animator and

```
otherAnimator = otherObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
```

for this.

Every time I now run my code, my game freezes but doesn't crash (I think it is stuck in a loop but there are no real loops in my program). It isn't my instantiation of the bullet before anyone starts accusing that as the loop of it freezing as I have commented this out and changed things around over and over again.

```
public class HurtPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

public float timeToShoot;
private float timeToShootCounter;
private bool shot;
private Vector3 moveDirection;
public float timeBetweenShot;
public float timeBetweenShotCounter;

public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject Bullet;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    shot = false;
    timeToShootCounter = timeToShoot;
    timeBetweenShotCounter = timeBetweenShot;
}

IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(float time)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (shot == true)
    {
        timeBetweenShot -= Time.deltaTime;
        timeToShoot -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeBetweenShot <= 0f)
        {
            shot = false;
            timeToShoot = timeToShootCounter;
            timeBetweenShot = timeBetweenShotCounter;
        }
    }       
}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")
    {
        if(shot == false)
        {
            if (timeToShoot >= 0f)
            {
                shot = true;
                while(shot == true)
                {
                    Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
                    if (timeBetweenShot <= 0f)
                    {
                        shot = false;
                        timeToShoot = timeToShootCounter;
                        timeBetweenShot = timeBetweenShotCounter;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This here is my code attached to my guard which instantiates a bullet as well as trying to use variables "TimeToShoot" as a counter for how long the enemy has left to shoot for and "TimeBetweenShoot" as a counter for how long the enemy has in between shots.

This doesn't work and neither does the `Enumerator` delay.

As an amateur I am obviously doing something clearly wrong but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or where and would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You **do have** a loop in your code.

Comment: Check if this if-clause `if (timeBetweenShot <= 0f)` is ever true - probably that's causing the freeze, as the `shot = false;` is never set. Also, as Dymanoid mentioned, `while` is also a loop ;)

Comment: Do not edit your post to remove your code like you did, it made the answers reference something that was not in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(shot == true)
```

this will freeze the editor if the body is never left

```
if (timeBetweenShot <= 0f)
{
    shot = false;
```

if this is not executed in the first iteration, it won't be in the second because you never change the value of "timeBetweenShot" in that loop

It is important to understand that your update function needs to terminate for the game frame to continue with the next game object's update etc, until the end of the frame is reached, before the next update is called on this game object in the next game frame, so

```
void Update () {
if (shot == true)
{
    timeBetweenShot -= Time.deltaTime;
```

is never executed while your while loop goes rogue

**EDIT:**

try something like:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (timeToShoot >= 0f) // if we are shooting at all
    {
        timeToShootCounter -= Time.deltaTime; // make sure we'll stop shooting after the given amount of time (decrease countdown until negative
        timeBetweenShotCounter -= Time.deltaTime; // decrease countdown until next shot (after some intervall)

        if (timeBetweenShotCounter <= 0f) // if intervall since last shot expired
        {
            Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation); // shoot
            timeBetweenShotCounter += timeBetweenShot; // add the time to wait for the next shot to the intervall (so that we don't shoot anymore in the following frames, until this time expired again (by becoming negative))
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")
    {
        timeToShootCounter = -1f; // initialise as expired (start shooting immediately)
        timeBetweenShotCounter = timeBetweenShot; // shoot in intervalls for this amount of time
    }
}
```

this way, when the collision event is triggered, you reset the counters to their initial values. After that the update function makes sure to fire after intervals of time, and stops once the overall shooting time is over.

Of course you can further improve this code to handle edge cases (if overall time expires and intervals time also expires at the same time, do we shoot a last bullet or not? etc)

hope this helps.
If you appreciate my efforts, please give them a thumbs up =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your loop: you increase `timeBetweenShot` on each frame but your while have to be executed in one frame, this `means` your code executes this `while` until you enter the `if` statement but you will never do since `timeBetweenShot` will change value only in next frame

```
            while(shot == true)// here is your loop budy
            {
// shot = false; // try this row here you will problably stop having the trouble
                Instantiate(Bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
                if (timeBetweenShot <= 0f)//
                {
                    shot = false;
                    timeToShoot = timeToShootCounter;
                    timeBetweenShot = timeBetweenShotCounter;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done and my Code now doesn't freeze :)